# using preg_match to strip specified underscore in php

Tags: php, regex, pcre

There has always been a confusion with preg_match in php.
 I have a string like this:

`apsd_01_03s_somedescription`
`apsd_02_04_somedescription`

Can I use preg_match to strip off anything from 3rd underscore including the 3rd underscore.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/^([^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*).*/', '$1', $str)
```

This will take only the first three sequences that are separated by `_`. So everything from the third `_` on will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to strip the "_somedescription" part:

```
 preg_replace('/([^]*)([^]*)([^]*)(.*)/', '$1_$2_$3', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gumbo's answer, however, instead of using regular expressions, you can use PHP's array functions:

```
$s = "apsd_01_03s_somedescription";

$parts = explode("_", $s);
echo implode("_", array_slice($parts, 0, 3));
// apsd_01_03s
```

This method appears to execute similarly in speed, compared to a regular expression solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the third underscore is the last one, you can do this:

```
preg_replace('/^(.+)_.+?)$/', $1, $str);
```